# Question on searching a string using regex and storing in a List

Tags: c#, string

Below is code used to search a string where Identity=" " exists and stores that line in a List.  I need to add to this search so that it not only picks up Identity=" " but ALSO where FrameworkSiteID=" ".  How can I modify the below code to do this?

Many thanks.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> IdentityLines = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

foreach(FileInfo file in Files) 
            { 
                string line = "";
                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName)) 
                { 
                        while(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line = sr.ReadLine())) 
                        {
                            if (line.ToUpper().Contains("IDENTITY="))
                            {
                                string login = reg.Match(line).Groups[0].Value;
                                IdentityLines.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, login));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                IdentityLines.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name,"NO LOGIN"));
                            }
                        }
                    //More additional code, not included..
```

Comment: Can anyone help?  best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

```
static void TestRegularExpression()
{
    String line = "Some text here, blah blah Identity=\"EDN\\nuckol\" and FRAMEworkSiteID=\"DesotoGeneral\" and other stuff.";
    Match m1 = Regex.Match(line, "((identity)(=)('|\")([a-zA-Z]*)([\\\\]*)([a-zA-Z]*)('|\"))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match m2 = Regex.Match(line, "((frameworkSiteID)(=)('|\")([a-zA-Z]*)('|\"))", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (m1.Success && m2.Success)
    {
        //...
        Console.WriteLine("Success!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Here's a regular expression tester I like to use.
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

-Matt

Comment: Hi Matt-

I've tried your exact code (well I just had to change the parentheses in each case because one had too many and the other didn't have enough) but it never enters the If statement.  I know the strings it's searching against have those substrings so I'm not sure what the deal is.  I'll keep inspecting the code.

Comment: Hey Josh, sorry about that.  I'm working with an injured hand so I fat finger all of my code these days.  I updated my post to reflect the exact code I used to test this.  It worked fine for me.  Maybe if you could post the text you need to match, I could test it.

Comment: Here is an example of my strings. I'm still not having any luck but I'll keep trying. <Event Timestamp="2010-08-05T07:16:09.7653762-05:00" Level="INFO" Identity="EDN\nuckol"><Message><Properties IP="175.1.118.61" FrameworkSiteID="DesotoGeneral" User="EDN\nuckol" /><ExtentChanged MinX="1461523" MinY="155555" MaxX="211111" MaxY="1233334" /></Message></Event>

Comment: That string will return false because Identity has a value.  Here's your original question:
"Below is code used to search a string where Identity=" " exists and stores that line in a List. I need to add to this search so that it not only picks up Identity=" " but ALSO where FrameworkSiteID=" ". How can I modify the below code to do this?"

So, here's my question:  Do you want identity to be returned whether or not it has a value.  When you ask programmers questions, the more detailed and specific the question, the better the answer usually. :-)

Comment: Yes I would like Identity to be returned With the value so Identity="EDN\nuckol" needs to get returned as does FrameworkSiteID="DesotoGeneral"

Comment: Okay, I updated the code.  This code assumes that Identity has a value of 0 or more alphas + 0 or more '\' + 0 or more alphas.
For FrameworkSiteID, I only search for 0 or more alphas.

Hope this helps.
-Matt

Comment: BTW, this code also assumes that your xml is all part of one line.

Comment: Thanks Matt-  so once I get inside that If Statement how can I add Both values to the List?  the Identity="EDN\nuckol" and the value of FrameworkSiteID="DesotoGeneral"  When I use my line of code below it just adds the Identity="EDN\nuckol"

Comment: sorry here is what I have inside my If statement. string login = reg.Match(line).Groups[0].Value; IdentityLines.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(file.Name, login));

Comment: I think I got it. Thanks Matt

Comment: No problem.  You should be able to just do String.Split() on m1.Value.ToString() no get the key/value pairs.